# GCM in iOS - clarification

Tags: ios, google-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

Just wanted to conform if my understanding is correct. As per my understanding, the mechanism involved in delivering the push notification to iOS App is `Server -> GCM -> APNS -> iOS App`. I am an iOS developer and I know that Apple strictly never allows a server other than APNS server to send a remote notification to iOS App. So, just wanted to know whether the notification is directly pushed to the iOS App from GCM or, via APNS.

Comment: Hope it will help someone: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33339774/gcm-google-cloud-messaging-for-ios-apps/35546895#35546895#answer-35546895

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Push messages are always sent by APNS.

What services like **Google Cloud Messaging** or **Parse.com** do is facilitating the administration of push messages - eg enabling an app to switch pushon or off for an app, or group users so you can send push messages to certain user groups instead of all of them.

Comment: The data payload and notification payload are both applicable on iOS & Android. On iOS the difference is that notification payload is sent through APNS while data payload is sent through GCM's own connection which is only there when app is in foreground. SO,If I want to use GCM in both android and ios,the payload should contain only notification?or is both data and notification is fine?

Answer (score 2):

GCM is not involved in Push Notification in iOS.
It is carried out through APNS.
Please refer 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html

It will clear all your doubts.

Comment: The question is asking about how GCM for iOS delivers notifications.

Answer (score 1):

Everything will be clear if you just look at image:

[image]

Its showing complete APNS process. This is the process for iOS, no GCM included for iOS.

Comment: The question is asking about how GCM for iOS delivers notifications. When using GCM for iOS, "your server" would talk to Google's GCM service.

Comment: The data payload and notification payload are both applicable on iOS & Android. On iOS the difference is that notification payload is sent through APNS while data payload is sent through GCM's own connection which is only there when app is in foreground. SO,If I want to use GCM in both android and ios,the payload should contain only notification?or is both data and notification is fine?