# Do I need to register to APNs to use GCM Push notifications in iOS?

Tags: ios, google-cloud-messaging, cordova-plugins

I am building a hybrid APP with cordova. I am using the phonegap-plugin-push to register to GCM so i can push notifications to Android.

My question is if i need the APNs certificates to be able to use GCM in iOS, or if with the plugin alone and the registration to GCM is enough?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer, Yes. You must then upload your APNs Certificate to GCM. Check out this *Route 85* video about [Sending Notifications on iOS through GCM](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WdCXm_CroIs).

Other useful links for you:

- https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/start
- https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/client
- https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/certs

Possibly similar post: [iOS support for Google Cloud Messaging](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15578280/4625829)