# Are all fields in each iOS app's General settings in Firebase required for push notifications?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

In the Firebase Console, under the General tab for a project's Settings, each iOS app in the project has a tab with fields for App ID, Bundle ID, App Store ID, and Team ID. Are all of these fields required for push notifications to work? And is there any other documentation for them besides their little question mark buttons? I can't find anything in Firebase's support guides about setting up these fields.

Answer (score 2):

No, only App ID and Bundle ID are required for FCM. There are references to this in the documentation but it is scattered throughout the iOS guides section. Bundle ID is set when you add the app to your project documentation reference found [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup).

> When prompted, enter your app's bundle ID. It's important to enter the
>   bundle ID your app is using; this can only be set when you add an app
>   to your Firebase project.

Additional note on Bundle ID

> If you have multiple build variants with different bundle IDs defined, each app must be added to your project in Firebase console.

In regards to documentation on Team ID and App Store ID you can see some of that information [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/ios).

Team ID required for Dynamic Links SDK.

> Optional: Your app's App Store ID, used to send users to the App Store
>   when the app isn't installed

Comment: In addition to this, in order for FCM (same with GCM) to work, you need to register to APNs and upload the corresponding certificates. See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38506147/4625829).